# Microsoft Remote Desktop client failing to connect via Remote Desktop Gateway in AWS

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, microsoft

I am on Microsoft Remote Desktop Version 10.2.2 on macOS 10.14 (Mojave). The error log looks like the following.

> An error occurred while communicating with the Remote Desktop Gateway.
>   If this keeps happening, contact your network administrator for
>   assistance.
>
> Error code: 0x3000062

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that the EC2 instance requires a security group that allows incoming traffic to the following ports for the Remote Desktop Gateway Service.

- TCP/443
- UDP/3391